# Servicestack Test: Method not found: 'Int32 ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.CustomFieldAttribute.get_Order()

Tags: c#, postgresql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Trying to build integration test with connection to db in ServiceStack.
My ServiceStack app is working fine, but when I run simple test I got this error message in line:22

***System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Int32 ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.CustomFieldAttribute.get_Order()'.'***

There is a lite cod:

```
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.Data;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace oth.Tests.IntegrationTests
{
    public class AppHost2 : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        public AppHost2() : base("Customer REST Example", typeof(CustomerService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            var connectionString =  "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=test_1234;Username=postgres;Password=local";
            container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
                new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, PostgreSqlDialect.Provider));

            using var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open();
            db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Customer>();
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        [AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    
    [Route("/customers", "GET")]
    public class GetCustomers : IReturn<GetCustomersResponse> { }
    public class GetCustomersResponse
    {
        public List<Customer> Results { get; set; }
    }


    public class CustomerService : Service
    {
        public object Get(GetCustomers request)
        {
            return new GetCustomersResponse { Results = Db.Select<Customer>() };
        }
    }

    public class CustomerRestExample
    {
        const string BaseUri = "http://localhost:2000/";
        ServiceStackHost appHost;

        public CustomerRestExample()
        {
            //Start your AppHost on TestFixture SetUp
            appHost = new AppHost2()
                .Init()
                .Start(BaseUri);
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void OneTimeTearDown() => appHost.Dispose();

        /* Write your Integration Tests against the self-host instance */

        [Test]
        public void Run_Customer_REST_Example()
        {
            var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUri);

            var all = client.Get(new GetCustomers());
            Assert.That(all.Results.Count, Is.EqualTo(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you see a **missing type** or **missing method** exceptions when using the [MyGet pre-release packages](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#major-versions) it means you have a dirty installation (i.e. using pre-release packages from different build times).

In which case you'd need to [Clear your Nuget packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#clear-nuget-package-cache) and download the latest packages again, which ensures all your packages are from the latest same build:

```sh
$ dotnet nuget locals all -clear
```